# Fade in and Fade out effect doesn't work on IE8 for a text blink?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have done so far is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
blinkeffect('#txthelpline');
});
function blinkeffect(selector) {
    $(selector).fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).fadeIn('slow', function() {
            blinkeffect(this);
        });
    });
}
```

```
 <a href = "javascript:void(0)" id="txthelpline" 
            onclick ="document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'"        
                 style="color:yellow; margin-left:110px; font-size: large; font-weight: bold; font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; ">Helpline Numbers</a>
```

Helpline Numbers text successfully blinked on google chrome. But it doesn't works on IE8.

Comment: double check your snippet. You might missing `;` or unclosed tags or js related error

Comment: I have corrected the missing ; . But still it works on google chrome and not in IE8.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you loading?  You will need a 1.x version for IE 8.

Comment: **<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>**

use this jquery for IE 8 and its lower version,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IE8, that particular animation does not work on an `<a>` tag.  I'm not sure exactly why that is, but it is perhaps because it is not a block element, but rather an inline element.  In any case, the animation will work if you put the link in a `<div>` and animate that `<div>` container instead.

Here's your link changed to a `<div>`: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7909102/test2.html that will animate in IE8.